# Django prefetch_related with multiple filters

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say this is my hypothetical codebase:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()
    ...

class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Zoo(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="zoos")

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
    animal_type = CharField(max_length=200)
    zoo = models.ForeignKey(Zoo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="animals")

def animals_of_type_at_zoo(animal_type, zoo):
    return zoo.animals.filter(animal_type=animal_type)

def generate_report():
    report_data = {}
    animal_types = ["lion", "tiger", "bear", ...etc]
    locations = Location.objects.all()
    locations = locations.prefetch_related("zoos", "zoos__animals")
    for loc in locations.all():
        for zoo in locations.zoos.all():
            for animal in animal_types:
                report_data[loc.address.country][animal] += animals_of_type_at_zoo(animal, zoo).count()
    return report_data
```

My goal is to make `generate_report` faster using prefetching.  In this case I have added `locations.prefetch_related("zoos", "zoos__animals")`.  However, since `animals_of_type_at_zoo` uses a filter, it triggers another query.  My thought process was to prefetch each filter:

```
locations = locations.prefetch_related("zoos", "zoos__animals")
for animal in animal_types:
    locations = locations.prefetch_related(Prefetch("zoos_animals", queryset=Animals.objects.filter(animal_type=animal))
```

However `zoos_animals` can only be assigned once, I can't create multiple filters for this.

My goal here is to prefetch everything needed with minimal impact to the `animals_of_type_at_zoo` function as it is used in other parts of the codebase and I want to minimize impact on the rest of the application (testing and performance).  I had attempted to create custom object that override `filter` and would return the correct prefetch, but wasn't getting far.  I was hoping someone had already solved this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the fact that I can only assign a prefetch to `zoos_animals` once, and I have to prefetch to an existing attribute...*or do I*?  It turns out (after reading the documentation) you can assign the prefetch to any attribute using `to_attr`.  Doing this I can prefetch multiple queries, which I will have #animals DB calls instead of #animals * #zoos (which is fine for me as #animals in this setup typically < 5, though I may work it lower if I can)

The prefetches look just like I posted in the question, but with `attr_to`:

```
locations = locations.prefetch_related("zoos", "zoos__animals")
for animal in animal_types:
    locations = locations.prefetch_related(Prefetch("zoos__animals", attr_to=f"zoo__animals_{animal}" queryset=Animals.objects.filter(animal_type=animal))
```

Then make a change to `animals_of_type_at_zoo` that will use the prefetch if it exists.  This has minimal impact on the original functionality in that it will continue to return the original query when not prefetching.

```
def animals_of_type_at_zoo(animal_type, zoo):
    if hasattr(zoo.animals, f"zoo__animals_{animal_type}"):
        return getattr(zoo.animals, f"zoo__animals_{animal_type}")
    return zoo.animals.filter(animal_type=animal_type)
```

I'm still open to idea to improve upon this.